# rc.local and networking start order

Tags: debian, iptables

If I add `iptables-restore` to my `/etc/rc.local` script, will this be guaranteed to be executed before any networking is started by the OS?

The alternative is that there will be a brief period where my iptables rules are not followed - once networking services have started where the connection is established and `rc.local` actually running - is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, `rc.local` is executed at the end of runlevel scripts. It is **not** guaranteed to be executed **before** any networking and usually is invoked **after** networking scripts.
The safest place to call iptables-restore or firewall scripts in Debian would be `pre-up` section of `/etc/network/interfaces`. You can check `/usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples/network-interfaces.gz` or `man interfaces` for exact examples.

Comment: What about rc.sysinit or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a package designed for saving and restoring the iptables rules. You should get the desired results if you install `iptables-persistent`

Comment: This is not what the OP asked: he knows how to restore the firewall, and want to make sure networking is executed, at boot, after setting up the firewall. The ther answer addresses the OP correctly.